# why multiple alert were not called in order in IOS webview?

Tags: javascript, android, ios

```
let sharedParam = {
   title: 'aaa',
   context: 'bbb',
   imgUrl: '*****'
};
let content = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({
type: 0,
callback: "sxCallback",
data: shareParam
}));
alert(1);
window.location.href = `pajasla://commonBusiness?content=${content}`;
alert(2);
```

when I test in ios webview, alert(2) was called firstly, then alert(1) was called. This is the opposite of Android. Why?

Comment: Ohhh! I am scared of answering MR.President's question!

Comment: @YunCHEN oh...just answer the question if you know, and do not worry